# Reduce Lambda Term to Normal Form

Tags: lambda-calculus

I just learned about lambda calculus and I'm having issues trying to reduce

```
    (λx. (λy. y x) (λz. x z)) (λy. y y)
```

to its normal form. I get to `(λy. y (λy. y y) (λz. (λy. y y) z)` then get kind of lost. I don't know where to go from here, or if it's even correct.

Comment: this is not an answer. but you have to replace `(λy. y y)` with something like `(λw. w w)` before applying it to `λx` because `y` in `(λy. y x)` and `(λy. y y)` conflicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(λx. (λy. y x) (λz. x z)) (λy. y y)
```

As @ymonad notes, one of the `y` parameters needs to be renamed to avoid capture (conflating different variables that only coincidentally share the same name). Here I rename the latter instance (using *α*-equivalence):

```
(λx. (λy. y x) (λz. x z)) (λm. m m)
```

Next step is to *β*-reduce. In this expression we can do so in one of two places: we can either reduce the outermost application (`λx`) or the inner application (`λy`). I'm going to do the latter, mostly on arbitrary whim / because I thought ahead a little bit and think it will result in shorter intermediate expressions:

```
(λx. (λz. x z) x) (λm. m m)
```

Still more *β*-reduction to do. Again I'm going to choose the inner expression because I can see where this is going, but it doesn't actually matter in this case, I'll get the same final answer regardless:

```
(λx. x x) (λm. m m)
```

Side note: these two lambda expressions (which are also known as the "Mockingbird" (as per Raymond Smullyan)) are actually *α*-equivalent, and the entire expression is the (in)famous Ω-combinator. If we ignore all that however, and apply another *β*-reduction:

```
(λm. m m) (λm. m m)
```

Ah, that's still *β*-reducible. Or is it? This expression is *α*-equivalent to the previous. Oh dear, we appear to have found ourselves stuck in an infinite loop, as is always possible in Turing-complete (or should we say Lambda-complete?) languages. One might denote this as our original expression equalling "bottom" (in Haskell parlance), denoted ⊥:

```
(λx. (λy. y x) (λz. x z)) (λy. y y) = ⊥
```

Is this a mistake? Well, some good LC theory to know is:

- *if* an expression has a *β*-normal form, then it will be the same *β*-normal form no matter what order of reductions was used to reach it, and
- *if* an expression has a *β*-normal form, then *normal order* evaluation is guaranteed to find it.

So what is *normal order*? In short, it is *β*-reducing the outermost expression at every step. Let's take this expression for another spin!

```
(λx. (λy. y x) (λz. x z)) (λm. m m)
(λy. y (λm. m m)) (λz. (λm. m m) z)
(λz. (λm. m m) z) (λm. m m)
(λm. m m) (λm. m m)
```

Darn. Looks like this expression has no normal form – it *diverges* (doesn't terminate).